# exercise: limit orthonormal sequence, "Banach Space Theory"

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have an exercise from "Banach Space Theory":
Suppose $\{x^k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal sequence in $l_2$, where $x^k:=(x_i^k)$. Show  that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_i^k =0 \ \forall_{i\in N}$.
Hint: Use the Bessel inequality to show that $(e_i,x^k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Can you help me?

Comment: Bessel will tell you that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |(e_i, x^k)|^2$ converges. What then is the limit of $|(e_i, x^k)|$ as $k$ tends to $\infty$? How are $(e_i, x^k)$ and $x_i^k$ related?

Comment: @DavidMitra Why don't you post this comment as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Bessel will tell you that for each $i$, the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty|(e_i,x^k)|^2$ converges (here, $e_i$ is the $i^{\rm th}$-standard unit vector in $\ell_2$).

That should be all you need. But if not, here are two questions to consider:  In light of the convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty|(e_i,x^k)|^2$, what then is the limit of $|(e_i,x^k)|$ as $k$ tends to $\infty$?   How are the quantities $(e_i,x^k)$ and $x^k_i$ related?

Comment: I don't understand this exercise, can You explain it more specifically?

Comment: @Anna Members of $\ell_2$ are infinite sequences, so $(x^k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is an infinite sequence of infinite sequences. What the problem requires is to show that for each $i$, the sequence of coordinates $(x^k_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$. If you write an infinite matrix whose $k$th  row is the vector  $x^k$, then you need to show that each column of the matrix tends to $0$ "as you look down".    Now fix $i$. The vector $e_i$ has $i$th coordinate $1$ and the rest $0$. The quantity $(e_i,x^k)$ is simply the $i$th coordinate of the vector $x^k$. For $i$ fixed, bessel applied to $e_i$...

Comment: and the sequence $(x^k)$ gives $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |(e_i,x^k)|^2\le 1$.  This tells you, since you have a convergent infinite sum, that $(e_i,x^k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow0$.  But again, $(e_i, x^k)=x^k_i$ (the $i$th coordinate of $x^k$ is denoted $x^k_i$). So, $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x^k_i=0$ for each $i$.

Comment: @Anna You're welcome. I have a typo in the first comment: the "sequence of coordinates" is $(x_i^k)_{\color{maroon}k=1}^\infty$, not $(x_i^k)_{\color{maroon}i=1}^\infty$. A typo in the second comment: in the second line "as $k\rightarrow\infty$", not "as $k\rightarrow0$".

Comment: I have one more question: how we know that $(e_i,x^k) \rightarrow 0$? I don't understand this step.

Comment: @Anna $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |(e_i,x^k)|^2$ is a convergent series. Thus its terms converge to $0$. So $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|(e_i,x^k)|^2=0$, which implies $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} (e_i,x^k) =0$.